# I am trying to install mysqli in my computer

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I try to install the Mysqli in my Ubuntu machine it gives the following error message:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mysqli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.0-mysql' instead of 'php-mysqli'
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 aptdaemon : Depends: python3-aptdaemon (= 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.2) but 1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14 is to be installed
 php7.0-mysql : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.14) but 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.6 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

After trying the solution given by my machine it now gives the following error:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon.pkcompat_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.2_all.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python3-aptdaemon_1.1.1+bzr982-0ubuntu14.2_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: What does it have to do with Python?